# Mocked value is not returned

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I have two classes:

```
public class Foo {
    public int getInt(){
       return 10;
    } 
}

public class Bar {
    Foo testClass = new Foo();

    public Foo getTestClass() {
        return testClass;
    }

    public void setTestClass(Foo testClass) {
       this.testClass = testClass;
    }

    public int get(){
        return testClass.getInt();
    }
}
```

And finally I have test class with mock for Foo:

```
public class TestClass {

    Foo test;

    @Before
    public void init(){
        test = Mockito.mock(Foo.class);
        Mockito.when(test.getInt()).thenReturn(5);
    }

    @Test
    public void tst(){
        Bar t = new Bar();
        Assert.assertEquals(t.get(), 5);

    }
}
```

Could you tell me, why I'm getting 10 from t.get() although in mock "I say" that I want 5 ?

How can I write Mock to get mocking value?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems your mock is not setted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to actually *set* your mock with a call to `t.setTestClass(test);`.

Comment: What if method setTestClass will be protected? Now I can not use t.setTestClass

Comment: Then you could either change your constructor to inject the mock from there, or you could make the setter accessible through reflection.

Answer (score 0):

When you're writing :

```
public class TestClass {

    Foo test;

    @Before
    public void init(){
        test = Mockito.mock(Foo.class);
        Mockito.when(test.getInt()).thenReturn(5);
    }

    @Test
    public void tst(){
        Bar t = new Bar();
        Assert.assertEquals(t.get(), 5);
    }
}
```

You are mocking your `Foo` class, but not using it in the `Bar` class. So if you call the return method, it won't send the result you tried to mock